# Passing ecrypted id in url parameter using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, url

Can any one tell me how to pass encrypted id in url using JS like as localhost/data?action=23 convert 23 to encrypt

I have already tried

- btoa()
- atob()

but these convert only string I want to convert id in encrypted form in url parameter

```
var action= id;

localhost/data.php?action=encrypt(id)
```

Comment: Since you want to encrypt data, If possible, it would be better to pass your data in the body, as it more secure there than in a query string.

Comment: What kind of encryption??? Base64, ROT13, Triple DES, RSA, AES...there are **thousands** of encryption methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var encodedData = window.btoa(1); // encode a string
var decodedData = window.atob(encodedData); // decode the string
alert(encodedData);
</script>
```

You can try above functions to encode and decode

Comment: Sir Please you tell me how i access these parameter from url  in other page it give me (mlf==) against id =1

Comment: var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var action = urlParams.get('action');

Comment: You can try above to get action from URL in another page

Comment: actual_id = window.atob(action)

Answer (score 0):

Why you need encrypt in javascript? If you want to protect data submit (user cannot change) you can use oAuth by token.

> Example: url: **http://aaa.com/user/delete/23**
>
> Url protect: **http://aaa.com/user/delete/23/token/aaaaaaaaaaaa...**
>
> Step1: when login, create a session variable "secuKeyInSession" with
>   random anything and md5 it. Ex: **secuKeyInSession = "bbbbbbbb"**
>
> Step2: when create link, make token parameter like: **token =
>   md5(secuKeyInSession . "23" . "user/delete")**
>
> Step3: when user submit or call link, double check and compare.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [crypto-js](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js) for encryption and decryption